# blog vs custom website content update

Tags: web, cpanel, blogs, web-hosting

i have a project with a friend and its about developing a website which will provide the users with some courses on certain topics. 
And we were wondering on how we are going to be updating the lessons notes and posting new ones without any problem. And he said the cpanel provided by the host company will provided a means to post just like on blogs. So i doubted and i'll like to ask if it true or i'll have to code a new page for every topic on the site.

Please i'll appreciate if any one helps me with the truth or a guide on how to do it.
 thanks...

Comment: sorry for changing the question it's just bc SO could not let me ask many questions at a time. so i have to bring this new question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point for you is to use [github](https://github.com/) to host a code repository you [start with git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics). If you use github, you can utilize [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) to host your content for free.

If you already have a hosting framework in mind like WAMP or heroku, let us know and we can provide more specific information on how to push your code up to your application depending on how you're hosting it. But the best starting point for you is to use some sort of version control and the leading version control option is git. You definitely never need to rewrite the same code all over again and version control is essential for managing updates to your code and collaborating with other developers.

Comment: thanks alot...   really i haven't yet hosted it was thinking of how to update the content after hosting.

Comment: i'll start with github then but don't know how it will help me update the content of my website